# disable onmouseover works in IE9 but not in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, mouseover, onmouseover

i have a little script that disables the onmouseover event that was created.

```
function disableHovers() {
        var table = document.getElementById("matrix");
        table.onmouseout = "#";
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
           for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                col.onmouseover = "#";
           }  
        }
    }
```

the problem is that it works on IE9 but not on IE8. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: is this called in a dom readystate?

Comment: why are you assigning a string to a function?

Comment: @DanielA.White If it works on a certain browser already, I'd guess that's already taken care of. As for assigning a string...haha

Comment: Instead of assigning `"#"`, try creating a function: `function noop() {}` outside of `disableHovers` and use `.onmouseout = noop;`

Comment: Does your code actually "disable" events bound with `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`?

Comment: Ian, tried the empty function still nothing, as far as events bound with the addeventlistener or attachevent i never created the event using those i have another function that creates the table and in a similiar fashion sets the .onmouseout to a function and when the browser loads that part works. its turning it off thats not working.